# React Native delay `AppRegistry.registerComponent`

Tags: react-native

I want to load some data from an API and then start of the application. How can I do that.
There is some documentation on the `AppRegistry` API here https://reactnative.dev/docs/appregistry but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

// I want to delay this part
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: you can delay `AppRegistry.runApplication`

Comment: @sebastian-ruehmann Do you have any example code ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I was able to find out how to do this in case some else has the same question

```js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerRunnable(appName, async initialProps => {
  try {
    await someAsyncTask();
    const App = require('./App').default;
    AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
    AppRegistry.runApplication(appName, initialProps);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to delay the `AppRegistry` you should show your users a loading screen while you fetch the data you need for your app. That way your users don't feel like your app is broken. It also improves your overall UX.

You can do this by using the `useEffect` hook. The example below uses React on the web, but the concept is the same for React Native - just swap out the HTML with Views, etc:

```
import React from "react";

// Mock API call
const getTestData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve({ data: "hello" });
  }, 5000);
});

export default function App() {
  const [state, updateState] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getTestData.then(res => {
      updateState(res);
    });
  }, []);

  if (state) {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <h2>Message: {state.data}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
}
```

Here's a [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-swartz-stfs6?file=/src/App.js) that shows the concept in action.

Comment: Your method is viable too but we all have reasons for very specific solutions sometimes. In terms of UX, deferring the application from running means the app will stay in the splash screen for a longer time… and that is one of the reasons why we have splash screens — to have some content to display while the app is loading. Also, [this React blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/11/06/building-great-user-experiences-with-concurrent-mode-and-suspense.html) mentions that "users will generally perceive the one with fewer intermediate loading states and fewer layout changes as having loaded faster".